# How was this hand played? Any leaks I should be concerned about?

Tags: texas-hold-em, online, cash-game, pre-flop

#### Game Info

- 0.25/0.50
- Online
- Cash Game
- 6-handed

#### Hand Info

- Cards: A9s (Hearts)
- Hero Position: Small Blind (SB)

#### Other Info

- Only 2nd hand played ... just joined about 8 hands ago
- No reads on any players

#### Pre-Flop

- BTN: Raise $1.10
- SB: Raise $3.30
- BTN: Raise $8.34
- SB: Call $5.21

#### Flop: 7h 5h Kd

- SB: Bet $17.18 (Pot)
- BTN: Raise $62.28 (All-In)
- SB: Call $24.82
- BTN: Shows KAs (Spades) [Pair of Kings - 63.33%]
- SB: Shows A9s (Hearts) [Flush Draw - 36.67%]

#### Turn: 9c

- Few more outs [Pair of 9s for the hero now...]

#### River: Js

- No help

#### My analysis

- My raise pre-flop was too aggressive with a mediocre starting hand (A9s) with zero reads on any players...I should have folded after the 3-bet from the BTN.
- I got myself into trouble pre-flop and after the two hearts on the flop would not have been able to get away from the hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hand, your problems are definitely coming from the action preflop.

I dont like how you 3-bet to $3.30 with A9s, but it isn't terrible because you do block an ace and the initial raiser was on the button, potentially making their raising range a bit wider.

The biggest glaring mistake here to me was your call after the button 4-bet you preflop. Going back to your initial intention with the 3-bet, ask yourself what you were trying to accomplish. If the 3-bet was a bluff, you now are facing a 4-bet and your only reasonable options are to raise and continue the bluff or give up. If your intention with the 3-bet was value, then the 4-bet here means your opponent likely has a better hand than you unless you have a soul read that they are capable of 4-betting as a bluff. Either way you should never be calling the 4-bet here.

The way I would play this preflop is either call or fold the button raise, or if you insist on 3-betting it is a 100% fold after you get 4-bet.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Clarko's excellent answer, I also don't like the lead post-flop. The awkward sizing commits you even when you're sure you're behind. K-high dryish boards favour your villain's range. AA, KK, AK are hands you're probably shoving preflop, but he could definitely have. I don't think 55, 77, or two pairs should be had by either of you, but K7s, K5s, or 75s are at least a *tiny bit* more likely as a crazy 4-bet bluff on the button. You might have KTs, KJs, KQs, but these are too weak to lead I think. Also, sometimes I like 4-bet bluffing offsuit broadways from the button because of good blockers, so if I were your villain sometimes I might have a random KTo, KJo, and KQo too (not sure if my thinking here about 4-betting is "correct" though). All this to say, I think your range is very much behind his here. If you play the way you did preflop, I think you should check-call the flop.